# Search and Replace words using SED utility

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have more than hundreds files (file1.txt ,file2.txt.....filen.txt) with below contents in Unix box.

file1.txt
location: $test/$type/path1/abc/testtable_123/
table: $database.testtable_123

file2.txt
location: $test/$type/path1/abc/testtable_345/
table: $database.testtable_345

I need your help to replace above lines with below contents in all the files (file1.txt...filen.txt) using sed (or awk , other ) utility in Unix.

file1.txt
location: $test/$type/**path2/path3/**abc/testtable_123/
table: **$test_database**.testtable_123

file2.txt
location: $test/$type/**path2/path3**/abc/testtable_345/
table: **$test_database**.testtable_345

Answer (score 1):

**You should back up your files before running these commands in case I've misunderstood or stuffed something up.**

The find command at the beginning searches for files matching "file*.txt" and outputs them as a null separated list.  The xargs -0 parses that null separated list and feeds it to sed.

For sed - I used  | as a seperator rather then the more common / because / is part of the string we are trying to replace.  the -i means "in place", so it modifies the file.

```
 find . -type f -name "file*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's|path1|path2/path3|g'
```

Next change $database to $test_database

```
find . -type f -name "file*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's|$database|$test_database|g'
```